# Does this Javascript code cause an infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, optimization

I'm trying to practice my Javascript chops. For some reasons, whenever I put

```
function swap ( pair )
{
    temp = pair.first;
    pair.first = pair.second;
    pair.second = temp;
}

function stable_partition ( arr, unpred )
{
    // each x in arr for which upred(x)=true is
    // moved to the right and each for which
    // unpred(x)=false is moved to the left of
    // the array arr

    var i = 0, j = (arr.length - 1);
    while (i < j)
    {
        while ( !unpred(arr[i]) && (i < j) ) ++i;
        while (  unpred(arr[j]) && (i < j) ) --j;
        swap({ first : arr[i], second: arr[j] });
    }
}

var MyUnaryPredicate = function (x) { return x == 0; }
var MyArray = [0, 0, 4, 0, 69, 1932];
stable_partition(MyArray,MyUnaryPredicate); // should move all the zeros to the back of MyArray

for (var k = 0, n = MyArray.length; k < n; ++k) $('#resultdiv').append(MyArray[k] + ' ');
```

into [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) the CPU used by Google Chrome shoots, my computer sounds like it's going to explode and the code never finishes running. Is there anything wrong with my code or is my computer bunk?

In addition, I'm wondering if I can cut down on a slight redundant operations in the procedure

```
while (i < j)
{
    while ( !unpred(arr[i]) && (i < j) ) ++i;
    while (  unpred(arr[j]) && (i < j) ) --j;
    swap({ first : arr[i], second: arr[j] });
}
```

because each time the body of the loop is entered, `i < j` is checked two unnessary times (since it was already checked at the `while` condition).

Comment: Your `swap` function does two things: 1) It changes the global `temp` variable. 2) It modifies the object that was passed in. Your call to `swap` passes a temporary object: `swap({...});` That object is destroyed after the function returns, so it doesn't matter that it was modified (and you're not making use of `window.temp`). Your `swap` call has no effect.

Comment: I thought that objects are passed as references. The was why I used an object to get `arr[i]` and `arr[j]` into the function.

Comment: Yes, that's why the function is able to modify the caller's object. But the values in the object are simply copies of `arr[i]` and `arr[j]`, which remain untouched.

Comment: @melpomene So what do you suggest for how to implement a real `swap` function?

Comment: You should use something like `swap(arr, i, j)`. If you don't have any reference to `arr`, you won't be able to modify it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a swap function like this

```
function swap(arr, first, second) {
  var temp = arr[first];
  arr[first] = arr[second];
  arr[second] = temp;
}
```

Also it is possible to make the while loop slightly shorter but it won't run any faster.

```
while (i < j)
{
    if(!unpred(arr[i])) ++i;
    else if(unpred(arr[j])) --j;
    else swap(arr, i, j);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is having all the elements satisfying the predicate to the left and all the others to the right (or vice versa, you just need to adjust the return value), I think you're much better off with something like this:

```
function stable_partition ( arr, unpred )
{
    var retArray1 = [];
    var retArray2 = [];
    var retArrayIndex1 = 0;
    var retArrayIndex2 = 0;

    for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        if (!unpred(arr[i]))
        {
            retArray1[retArrayIndex1] = arr[i];
            retArrayIndex1++;
        } else {
            retArray2[retArrayIndex2] = arr[i];
            retArrayIndex2++;
        }
    }

    return retArray1.concat(retArray2);
}
```